# Pull moment() js from a server and not a local pc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timezone

Is this possible, I am using a function in jQuery validate() to validate the date of birth to determine someones age, my question is if the person's pc has an incorrect date, this validation is no longer valid, how to get moment() to grab the exact date and time from a AUS Timezone server? so it ignores the PC's date and time?

Is this possible? Here is my function what can I do to improve this function so that current date and time is pulled from a server, but the exact moment() because I need to determine the age down the day.

I initially thought of echoing out php date in a hidden field and grabbing the val() by ID but that does not seem like the right way to do it.

```
//validate the date of birth to see if eligible you are eligible for enrolment using moment.js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateDob", function (value, element) {

    var birthDate = moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var currentDate = moment();

    currentDate.subtract("years", 18);

    if(!birthDate.isValid()){
        //if birthDate is NOT a valid date            
        return false;
    }else if (currentDate.isAfter(birthDate)){
        //birthDate is 18+
        return true;  
    }else{
        //birthDate is not 18  
        return false;
    }

}, "You must be 18 and over to proceed");
```

Comment: You could perform the front end check with the local time on their pc as well as on the server side (with server time) when they submit the form.

Comment: You could also send an ajax request in with the users given birthdate to compare it to the server time. This way you do not need to compare it with moment.js as you say, it depends on a date that they can tamper with.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself, not sure if it is the correct way of doing it by I managed to call the php date function in my php file, pass it to a hidden field.

Get the hidden field value by ID using jQuery and used that string to pass it in the moment() function like so:

php file

1. `$currentDate = date('d/m/Y');`

html file

2. `<input type="hidden" id="currentDate" value=" <?php echo $currentDate; ?>" />`

js file

3. `var dateString = $("#currentDate").val();
      moment(dateString, "DD/MM/YYYY")`

It seems to work as expected I have not had any issues using this method.